# Are the number of points I need to answer my own question uniform across all sites?

Tags: support

Are the number of points I need to answer my own question uniform across all sites?

I could find out by signing up spamming each area but that seems rude.

Answer (score 2):

You need 15 reputation to create a self-answered question; you should be able to post an answer to a question you've already asked at any time.

Answer (score -3):

It seems I can answer here with 101 points.